# Custom Validators - When to use Promise.reject() vs throw new Error()?

Tags: express-validator

In the [Custom Validators/Sanitizers documentation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html), it offers 2 methods to return an error along with a message.

```
body('email').custom(value => {
  return User.findUserByEmail(value).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
    }
  });
```

The following code also works:

```
body('email').custom(value => {
  return User.findUserByEmail(value).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      throw new Error('E-mail already in use');
    }
  });
```

I understand the Promise.reject() method is asynchronous, however it doesn't seem to make a difference in the actual code.

Is there a particular situation you would want to use `Promise.reject()` vs `throw new Error()`? Or are they just the same thing but different semantics?  And which method should be prioritized in situations where both methods work?